# CodeMirror vanishes when it hides the TextArea it is hooked into in Gentelella theme

Tags: jquery, html, css, codemirror, gentelella

Tested the codemirror script bundle I have compiled and it is working standalone with nothing else, however when I try and use the element inside the [gentelella](https://github.com/puikinsh/gentelella) theme, it loads with no errors, but on hide of the textarea, codemirror itself is hidden.  If I use Chrome debugger, the only way I can make codemirror visible, is to edit the textarea by adding `style="display: block !important;"`

Following is the code I am using for the [gentelella](https://github.com/puikinsh/gentelella) theme :

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
    <!-- Meta, title, CSS, favicons, etc. -->
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">

    <title>Dashboard</title>

    <!-- Bootstrap core CSS -->

    <link href="./templates/gentelella/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">

    <link href="./templates/gentelella/fonts/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="./templates/gentelella/css/animate.min.css" rel="stylesheet">

    <!-- Custom styling plus plugins -->
    <link href="./templates/gentelella/css/custom.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="./templates/gentelella/css/maps/jquery-jvectormap-2.0.3.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
    <link href="./templates/gentelella/css/icheck/flat/green.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="./templates/gentelella/css/floatexamples.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">

    <script src="./templates/gentelella/js/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="./templates/gentelella/js/nprogress.js"></script>

    <!-- HTML5 shim and Respond.js for IE8 support of HTML5 elements and media queries -->
    <!--[if lt IE 9]>
        <script src="./templates/gentelella/js/ie8-responsive-file-warning.js"></script>
        <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/html5shiv/3.7.2/html5shiv.min.js"></script>
        <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/respond/1.4.2/respond.min.js"></script>
    <![endif]-->
        <!-- CodeMirror -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="./templates/gentelella/js/codemirror/lib/codemirror.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="./templates/gentelella/js/codemirror/addon/hint/show-hint.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="./templates/gentelella/js/codemirror/theme/cobalt.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="./templates/gentelella/js/codemirror/addon/dialog/dialog.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="./templates/gentelella/js/codemirror/addon/hint/show-hint.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="./templates/gentelella/js/codemirror/addon/fold/foldgutter.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="./templates/gentelella/js/codemirror/addon/tern/tern.css" />
    </head>


<body class="nav-md">

  <div class="container body">

    <div class="main_container">

      <div class="col-md-3 left_col">
        <div class="left_col scroll-view">

          <div class="navbar nav_title" style="border: 0; height: 1px; overflow: hidden;">
            <a href="/app/" class="site_title"><i class="fa fa-edit"></i> <span>Dashboard</span></a>
            <br>
          </div>
          <div class="clearfix"></div>

          <!-- menu prile quick info -->
          <div class="profile">
            <div class="profile_pic">
              <img src="https://secure.gravatar.com/avatar/99fda7ae65e2d02e452f731d56ebe108" alt="Administrator" class="img-circle profile_img">
            </div>
            <div class="profile_info">
              <span>Welcome,</span>
              <h2>Administrator</h2>
            </div>
            <br>
          </div>
          <!-- /menu prile quick info -->

          <!-- sidebar menu -->
          <div id="sidebar-menu" class="main_menu_side hidden-print main_menu">

            <div class="menu_section">
              <h3>&nbsp;</h3>
              <ul class="nav side-menu">
                <li><a><i class="fa fa-home"></i> Home <span class="fa fa-chevron-down"></span></a>
                  <ul class="nav child_menu" style="display: none">
                    <li><a href="/app/">Dashboard</a></li>
                  </ul>
                </li>
              </ul>
            </div>

          </div>
          <!-- /sidebar menu -->

          <!-- /menu footer buttons -->
          <div class="sidebar-footer hidden-small">
            <a data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="top" title="Settings" href="/app/settings">
              <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-cog" aria-hidden="true"></span>
            </a>
            <a data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="top" title="FullScreen" onclick="fullscreen()" href="javascript:void(0);">
              <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-fullscreen" aria-hidden="true"></span>
            </a>
            <a data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="top" title="Foo" href="#">
              <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-lock" aria-hidden="true"></span>
            </a>
            <a data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="top" title="Logout" href="/app/logout">
              <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-off" aria-hidden="true"></span>
            </a>
          </div>
          <!-- /menu footer buttons -->
        </div>
      </div>

      <!-- top navigation -->
      <div class="top_nav">

        <div class="nav_menu">
          <nav class="" role="navigation">
            <div class="nav toggle">
              <a id="menu_toggle"><i class="fa fa-bars"></i></a>
            </div>

            <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
              <li class="">
                <a href="javascript:;" class="user-profile dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-expanded="false">
                  <img src="https://secure.gravatar.com/avatar/99fda7ae65e2d02e452f731d56ebe108" alt="Administrator">Administrator
                  <span class=" fa fa-angle-down"></span>
                </a>
                <ul class="dropdown-menu dropdown-usermenu pull-right">
                  <li><a href="/app/logout"><i class="fa fa-sign-out pull-right"></i> Log Out</a></li>
                </ul>
              </li>

                                <li role="presentation">
                    <a href="/app/notifications" alt="See All Notifications">
                        <i class="fa fa-envelope-o"></i>
                    </a>
                </li>

            </ul>
          </nav>
        </div>

      </div>
      <!-- /top navigation -->

      <!-- page content -->
      <div class="right_col" role="main">
<div class="row">
<textarea id="template" name="code"></textarea>
</div>
      </div>
      <!-- /page content -->
    </div>

  </div>

  <div id="custom_notifications" class="custom-notifications dsp_none">
    <ul class="list-unstyled notifications clearfix" data-tabbed_notifications="notif-group">
    </ul>
    <div class="clearfix"></div>
    <div id="notif-group" class="tabbed_notifications"></div>
  </div>

  <script src="./templates/gentelella/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

    <script src="./templates/gentelella/js/codemirror/lib/codemirror.js"></script>
  <script src="./templates/gentelella/js/codemirror/lib/codemirror-extras.js"></script>
  <script src="./templates/gentelella/js/codemirror/init.js"></script>

  <!-- gauge js -->
  <script type="text/javascript" src="./templates/gentelella/js/gauge/gauge.min.js"></script>
  <!-- bootstrap progress js -->
  <script src="./templates/gentelella/js/progressbar/bootstrap-progressbar.min.js"></script>
  <!-- icheck -->
  <script src="./templates/gentelella/js/icheck/icheck.min.js"></script>
  <!-- daterangepicker -->
  <script type="text/javascript" src="./templates/gentelella/js/moment/moment.min.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="./templates/gentelella/js/datepicker/daterangepicker.js"></script>
  <!-- chart js -->
  <script src="./templates/gentelella/js/chartjs/chart.min.js"></script>

  <script src="./templates/gentelella/js/custom.js"></script>

  <!-- flot js -->
  <!--[if lte IE 8]><script type="text/javascript" src="./templates/gentelella/js/excanvas.min.js"></script><![endif]-->
  <script type="text/javascript" src="./templates/gentelella/js/flot/jquery.flot.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="./templates/gentelella/js/flot/jquery.flot.pie.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="./templates/gentelella/js/flot/jquery.flot.orderBars.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="./templates/gentelella/js/flot/jquery.flot.time.min.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="./templates/gentelella/js/flot/date.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="./templates/gentelella/js/flot/jquery.flot.spline.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="./templates/gentelella/js/flot/jquery.flot.stack.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="./templates/gentelella/js/flot/curvedLines.js"></script>
<!--  <script type="text/javascript" src="./templates/gentelella/js/flot/jquery.flot.resize.js"></script>//-->

  <!-- worldmap -->
  <script type="text/javascript" src="./templates/gentelella/js/maps/jquery-jvectormap-2.0.3.min.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="./templates/gentelella/js/maps/gdp-data.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="./templates/gentelella/js/maps/jquery-jvectormap-world-mill-en.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="./templates/gentelella/js/maps/jquery-jvectormap-us-aea-en.js"></script>
  <!-- pace -->
  <script src="./templates/gentelella/js/pace/pace.min.js"></script>
  <!-- skycons -->
  <script src="./templates/gentelella/js/skycons/skycons.min.js"></script>

  <!-- PNotify -->
  <script type="text/javascript" src="./templates/gentelella/js/notify/pnotify.core.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="./templates/gentelella/js/notify/pnotify.buttons.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="./templates/gentelella/js/notify/pnotify.nonblock.js"></script>

  <script>
    function fullscreen() {
        var isInFullScreen = (document.fullscreenElement && document.fullscreenElement !== null) ||
            (document.webkitFullscreenElement && document.webkitFullscreenElement !== null) ||
            (document.mozFullScreenElement && document.mozFullScreenElement !== null) ||
            (document.msFullscreenElement && document.msFullscreenElement !== null);

        if (!isInFullScreen) {
            if (document.documentElement.requestFullscreen) {
                document.documentElement.requestFullscreen();
            } else if (document.documentElement.mozRequestFullScreen) {
                document.documentElement.mozRequestFullScreen();
            } else if (document.documentElement.webkitRequestFullScreen) {
                document.documentElement.webkitRequestFullScreen();
            } else if (document.documentElement.msRequestFullscreen) {
                document.documentElement.msRequestFullscreen();
            }
        } else {
            if (document.exitFullscreen) {
                document.exitFullscreen();
            } else if (document.webkitExitFullscreen) {
                document.webkitExitFullscreen();
            } else if (document.mozCancelFullScreen) {
                document.mozCancelFullScreen();
            } else if (document.msExitFullscreen) {
                document.msExitFullscreen();
            }
        }
    }

    NProgress.done();
  </script>
  <!-- /datepicker -->
  <!-- /footer content -->
</body>

</html>
```

This is what I get when viewing the page :

[image]

And if I change the style of `textarea` as described above :

[image]

And everything works normally except I can't get rid of the textarea (see picture below).

[image]

Even if I apply a style to the textarea (the same way in chrome live) to reposition it off screen, it actually ends up repositioning the CodeMirror block, and the textarea remains. (example style:  `position: absolute; top: -1000;` )

The only custom script that isn't part of [gentelella](https://github.com/puikinsh/gentelella) theme are as follows :

#### codemirror-extras.js

This is built using the [CodeMirror Builder](http://codemirror.net/doc/compress.html) with the following options selected:

```
   Version: HEAD

   CodeMirror Library:
   - codemirror.js
   Modes:
   - css.js
   - htmlembedded.js
   - htmlmixed.js
   - javascript.js
   - markdown.js
   - php.js
   - sql.js
   - vb.js
   - vbscript.js
   - xml.js
   Add-ons:
   - active-line.js
   - brace-fold.js
   - closebrackets.js
   - closetag.js
   - comment-fold.js
   - css-hint.js
   - dialog.js
   - foldcode.js
   - foldgutter.js
   - html-hint.js
   - javascript-hint.js
   - jump-to-line.js
   - markdown-fold.js
   - match-highlighter.js
   - matchbrackets.js
   - matchtags.js
   - overlay.js
   - search.js
   - searchcursor.js
   - show-hint.js
   - sql-hint.js
   - xml-fold.js
   - xml-hint.js
```

#### init.js

This just initializes CodeMirror with some options.

```
InitializeCodeMirror = true;
function completeAfter(cm, pred) {
    var cur = cm.getCursor();
    if (!pred || pred()) setTimeout(function() {
        if (!cm.state.completionActive)
            var doc = cm.getDoc();
            var POS = doc.getCursor();
            var mode = CodeMirror.innerMode(cm.getMode(), cm.getTokenAt(POS).state).mode.name;
            console.log(mode);
            if (mode == 'xml') { //html depends on xml
                CodeMirror.showHint(cm, CodeMirror.hint.html);
            } else if (mode == 'javascript') {
                CodeMirror.showHint(cm, CodeMirror.hint.javascript);
            } else if (mode == 'css') {
                CodeMirror.showHint(cm, CodeMirror.hint.css);
            }               
//                      cm.showHint({completeSingle: false});
    }, 100);
    return CodeMirror.Pass;
}

function completeIfAfterLt(cm) {
    return completeAfter(cm, function() {
        var cur = cm.getCursor();
        return cm.getRange(CodeMirror.Pos(cur.line, cur.ch - 1), cur) == "<";
    });
}

function completeIfInTag(cm) {
    return completeAfter(cm, function() {
        var tok = cm.getTokenAt(cm.getCursor());
        if (tok.type == "string" && (!/['"]/.test(tok.string.charAt(tok.string.length - 1)) || tok.string.length == 1)) return false;
        var inner = CodeMirror.innerMode(cm.getMode(), tok.state).state;
        return inner.tagName;
    });
}

function CodeMirrorInit(elementName) {
    cmInstance = CodeMirror.fromTextArea(document.getElementById(elementName), {
        mode: "htmlmixed",
        lineNumbers: true,
        autoCloseTags: true,
        autoCloseBrackets: true,
        foldGutter: true,
        styleActiveLine: true,
        theme: 'cobalt',
        gutters: ["CodeMirror-foldgutter", "CodeMirror-linenumbers"],
        autocomplete: true,
        extraKeys: {
            "'<'": completeAfter,
            "'/'": completeIfAfterLt,
            "' '": completeIfInTag,
            "'='": completeIfInTag,
            "'.'": completeAfter,
            "'{'": completeAfter,
            "':'": completeAfter,
            "Ctrl-Space": "autocomplete"
        }
    } );
}

function registerHotKeys() {
    $(window).bind('keydown', function(event) {
        if (event.ctrlKey || event.metaKey) {
            switch (String.fromCharCode(event.which).toLowerCase()) {
            case 's':
                event.preventDefault();
//                  jQuery.gritter.add({
//                      title: 'This is a regular notice!',
//                      text: 'This will fade out after a certain amount of time.',
//                      class_name: 'growl-success',
//                      image: '/se/template/images/screen.png',
//                      sticky: false,
//                      time: ''
//                  });
                //alert('ctrl-s');
                break;
//          case 'f':
//              event.preventDefault();
//              alert('ctrl-f');
//              break;
//          case 'g':
//              event.preventDefault();
//              alert('ctrl-g');
//              break;
            }
        }
    });
}
if(InitializeCodeMirror === true) {
    CodeMirrorInit('template');
    cmInstance.focus();
    cmInstance.setCursor(1);
    registerHotKeys();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Add div with class `x_content` or `col-md-*`